# Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, runtime, .net-framework-version

I'm having an issue that when i run my application on Service Fabric,
i get this exception, and also "FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x1e477a47, on thread 0x5b24. The error code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack".
When I go to the event viewer this is what I get as an exception when the application crashes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnxxS.png)
and also on service fabric:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZSmJ.png)

I tried to reinstall visual studio, service fabric, reinstalled windows, I tried the installation of the app on other computer, it appeared the same thing.
Somone that could give me paths how to fix this out?

I'm running my application on:
VS 2019 community,
.NET framework 4.6.1,
5.0.407 SDK,
Service fabric 9.1,
Sf SDK 5,
Windows 11

Regards,